# How to add OAuth2 login to an app using JWT authorization headers (without cookies)?

Tags: authentication, cookies, oauth-2.0, jwt, authorization

**Existing Login System (JWTs):** To authenticate users, my app's client sends a JWT to the server with each request. JWT's are stored in local storage and sent via the HTTP authorization header (i.e. `authorization: bearer <JWT>`)

**Adding Google Login (OAuth2):** I need to allow users to login with Google via OAuth2. I have a route on my server that begins the OAuth2 login flow with google. After this, my server creates an account for the user based on their Google account.

**The Problem:** After the sever finishes the OAuth2 login process, how can I redirect to the client with a JWT for future authentication? Is this possible using the http header authorization: bearer method? Do I need to restructure the app to use cookie-based auth?